# can bootstrap grid system divide vertical direction like 'col-xs-*'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can bootstrap grid system divide vertical direction like 'col-xs-*'? Or any css framework can do this ? I have two `div`, I want them fill the full page, each height is the half of the page, and can be responsive to different screen height

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your CSS. If you want to divide the page into two equal halves, you have to give each of your `row` a height property as `height: 50%;`

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.row{
    height: 50% 
}
```